# catalina.home not being recognized by intellij

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, catalina

I am using a property place holder to reference a file, it works when deployed, but intellij is not picking up the catalina home. I have tried setting windows environment varibale and path in intellij ide settings, makes no difference still shows an error (which borks my datasource in the ide) I could place the conf file in project directory instead, but then the project will not be portable to other tomcat installs without further jiggery pokery ....

[image: Darcula oo eerr, catalina home is a problem]

Surely there is a way that intellij will recognize and reference correctly ${catalina.home} within my spring application context ?

Sys variable is set up ok :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is an open [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-92348#comment=27-402599). However the workaround for me is to simply copy the properties file into project workspace (in my case the resources direcrtory), but keep the applicationContext.xml pointing at `${catalina.home}`.

Intellij then picks up the property values and then the datasource can be set up easily.